# Animated background like Timely alarm clock app

Tags: android, animation, background, effects, android-drawable

I've seen the [Timely app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.bitspin.timely&hl=es_419) and it let me hypnotized with their animated background, it has bubbles floating around and

Can you plase tellme how can I do that, I've tried AnimationDrawable and ValueAnimator with AnimatorSet but that seems diferent of the timely app used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps a good way to go about looking into this is to ask *how does Timely create these effects.* I took a look at the APK (for educational purposes) and found this in the package `ch.bitspin.timely.background`:

```
public class BackgroundView extends FrameLayout
{
  private BackgroundGradientView a;
  private BackgroundBeamsDotsView b;
  private BackgroundCircleEffectView c;
  private BackgroundBubblesView d;
```

The base of the Timely animation effects are through the use of a custom View, which you can find a guide on the [Android Developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html). Each of the above Views are hundreds of lines of code, but to summarize: they all utilize a background Thread that manipulates Bitmap, Paint, BitmapShader, and Canvas objects in the View's onDraw method.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the live wallpaper implementations by Android itself. This is very much close to the Timely app like effect.

The sources are in packages/wallpapers/Holospiral or packages/wallpapers/PhaseBeam.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/wallpapers/HoloSpiral/

They use renderscript to implement these.